# CPU cost in enabling mod_gzip

Tags: gzip

what is the cost of enabling compression in a server's response... I am assuming higher CPU utilization but confused on how many times is a response compressed. For instance if there are 10 requests in 1 second to Apache with compression enabled... are the responses compressed each time or there is some kind of cache mechanism

and what are other disadvantages that I may not be seeing

thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CPU load to compress a typical HTTP request is minimal.  We enable it on all our machines, the overhead is lost in the noise.  Scott Forsyth has an article on [the tradeoffs of compressions levels in IIS 7](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/02/22/iis-7-compression-good-bad-how-much.aspx) which, whilst not directly applicable to other situations, does give some ideas of how it might work in other situations.

Answer (score 2):

Enable the compression unless you have a reason not to. You pay for bandwidth, do you want to pay for less?